# How to restart explorer.exe with a batch file

Tags: windows-10, windows-explorer, batch

I need a batch file to stop and restart explorer.exe, but I don't know all the commands needed.  I know if you select it from the task manager you can restart it, but I want a file on my desktop I can double-click. I'm using Windows 10 Professional.

Answer (score 30, accepted):

Pretty simple to do this and pretty self-explanatory:

```
taskkill /im explorer.exe /f
start explorer.exe
exit
```

The `/im` makes it look for a process name. `/f` says to kill it forcefully, however your force is as powerful as the permissions you have.

Comment: thank you - it worked :D although the timeout command isn't necessary :/

Comment: also, explaining what each command does and why the flags used are necessary could help a future viewer of this question with a similar but not identical problem

Comment: Also adding `timeout` or `pause` command in between taskkill and start commands will give some time to restart.

Comment: Nice! I created a shortcut with this target: `C:\Windows\System32\cmd.exe /c taskkill /im explorer.exe /f & start explorer.exe` - bonus, you can assign this shortcut a hotkey to trigger it quickly and easily similar to how `Ctrl` + `Alt` + `Backspace` restarts the X server in Linux.

Answer (score 5):

To restart **Explorer** in **Windows 10**, I created a shortcut with the `Target`:

```
powershell -command "gps explorer | spps"
```

`gps` is the [Alias](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_aliases?view=powershell-5.1) for [Get-Process](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.management/get-process?view=powershell-5.1)

`spps` is the alias for [Stop-Process](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/Microsoft.PowerShell.Management/Stop-Process?view=powershell-5.1)