# Terminate & Restart Explorer.exe and it's child process to make folders and apps open faster

Tags: windows, windows-10, command-line, windows-explorer, batch

Now this may sound whimsical, but I want to know, can a batch script be made, that kills the Explorer.exe and it's child processes forcibly and then successfully starts the Explorer.exe process again, without having to run that Batch script again?

I tried the below code, but even after waiting for 10 mins, the Explorer.exe hasn't started yet, so I am afraid to add `/T` to the `taskkill`.

```
start /wait taskkill /IM explorer.exe /F
start "" explorer.exe /wait
```

How can I acheive something like this with batch script, in autonomous manner?

```
taskkill /IM /F Explorer.exe /T
start /wait Explorer.exe
```

Comment: This may be an [XY problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem/66378#66378). What makes you think that restarting explorer will make apps load faster?

Comment: The lag time required to restart Explorer is likely to exceed any time you might save

Comment: What was the result of adding T? same thing?

Comment: See if this helps>>>>>>>>https://superuser.com/questions/1245653/how-to-restart-explorer-exe-with-a-batch-file

Comment: Tried that already, it doesn't fire-up the explorer.exe.

Comment: **PowerShell** : `Get-Process explorer | Stop-Process` or `gps explorer | spps`

Comment: I just finished working on this problem and the only way you will get explorer running again is to Ctrl+Alt+Delete Task Manager File - Run new task - explorer.

Answer (score 0):

`start` command starts programs in unusual ways. It is not something that is used normally. In help for `start` (`start /?`) it discusses how to start programs normally and with `start`.

```
taskkill /IM explorer.exe /F
start explorer
```

First line. Console programs always wait when started normally. To have them not wait you use `start`.

Second line. GUI programs don't wait when started normally except in batch files for compatibility reasons. As you don't want to wait for explorer use `start` to not wait.

Also if you Ctrl+Shift+Right click a blank spot on the taskbar you will get an *Exit Explorer* option which will shut explorer down gracefully. Press Ctrl+Shift+Esc to start Task Manager and *File* menu - *Run New Task* and type explorer.

Answer (score -1):

Do `start /wait taskkill /IM explorer.exe /F` then `start /wait explorer` It work's for me.
NOTE: `/wait` will mean the command is never finished. Most programs are a child process of explorer meaning it can never fully start up.